# How can I create a set from a defrecord?

Tags: clojure

I have:

```
(defrecord human-being [uuid first-name last-name genome-sequence])

(defrecord space-ship [uuid ship-type engines home-world captain])
```

I want to have a single 'construction' function that will take records of either human-being or space-ship and return a set with the keys as the actual record keys:

```
(def john (human-being. "ABC123" "John" "Smith" "QWERTY"))
(def enterprise (space-ship. "ZXC123" "Galactic" "Warp" "Earth" "Picard"))

(constructFunc john) --returns--> {:uuid "ABC123" :first-name "John" :last-name "Smith" :genome-sequence "QWERTY"}

(constructFunc enterprise) --returns--> {:uuid "ZXC123" :ship-type "Galactic" :engines "Warp" :home-world "Earth" :captain "Picard"}
```

I don't just want these two defrecords. I need to be able to drop any defrecords in and get similar output...

I have a feeling I should be using macros for this, but that scares me somewhat....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, "I don't just want these two defrecords" so you want maps in a set ? `(into (hash-set) (map #(into {} %) [john enterprise]))` maybe ?

Comment: so I want to have a generic function which I can drop any kind of defrecord (perhaps not defined yet) and it just spits out a map...

Comment: `#(into {} %)` does that (or if you prefer a named fn `(defn ->map [r] (into {} r))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as the question is essantialy "how do I turn a Defrecord into a map" I can think of 4 more or less equivalent ways.

```
; direct - but this is stricly speaking not 'a function'
(into {} john)

; anonymous
( #(into {} %) john )

; named 
(defn ->map [r] 
  (into {} r))
(->map john)

; via composition/partial
( (partial into {}) john)    

; all of them return
{:uuid "ABC123", :first-name "John", :last-name "Smith", :genome-sequence "QWERTY"}
```

Comment: many thanks, so simple! Is there a way to get the 'type' of the defrecord as a string... eg: (typeOfRecord enterprise) ---> "space-ship" ?

Comment: `(type john)` or similar